# SumIF formula for calculating cells based on today() criteria

Tags: excel, wps

[image]

I am trying to calculate plan till date based on the sheet above. For instance, let say today is 5th of May. Then it should only sum plan target before and this date. So it should count 900+900+700+800.

I want it to use today() criteria so I don't have to manually edit anything.
Is this possible?
Let me know if you need any information, thanks!

Comment: If you want to use `SUMIF()` then you can use a formula like this `=SUMIF($C$4:$R$4,"<="&$D$16,INDEX($C$5:$R$9,MATCH($B17,$B$5:$B$9,0),0))` where `D16` refers to `TODAY()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D17`

```
=SUMIF($C$4:$R$4,"<="&$D$16,INDEX($C$5:$R$9,MATCH($B17,$B$5:$B$9,0),0))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C17`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:$B$9=$B17)*($C$4:$R$4<=$C$16)*$C$5:$R$9)
```

---

Or, If you are using `MS365` then with Dynamic Spill Array formulas.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E17`

```
=MAP(B17:B20,LAMBDA(m,SUM(FILTER($C$5:$R$9,m=$B$5:$B$9)*($C$4:$R$4<=E16))))
```

---

**Note:** `C16` `D16` & `E16` refers to `TODAY()`

Comment: I have tried using both the formulas, but it gives me 13600 instead of 3300. Is it because I am using WPS?

Comment: @rohannair have you tried hitting the `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. I am not sure about `WPS` and how it works.

Comment: @rohannair The sumproduct option shouldn't require an array and would work alone without any fancy arrays.